Python redmine get issue by name
I'm writing a script for Redmine in Python, I need to change the text of the issue in Redmine, knowing its name, I tried to take all the issue and go through the loop
def get_redmine_issue_name(subject):
    """
    Получает issue, у которых название (subject) точно совпадает с указанной строкой.
    """
    try:
        all_issues = redmine.issue.all()
        for issue in all_issues:
            if issue.subject == subject:
                return issue
        return None  # Если не найдено
    except Exception as e:
        raise

Breeds error
File "/home/petr/VScodeProjects/dbt.obsever/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/redminelib/engines/base.py", line 177, in process_response raise exceptions.ForbiddenError redminelib.exceptions.ForbiddenError: Requested resource is forbidden
Please tell me how this task can be implemented because issue.get can only be done by id
